# Adj.-s/Adjs/Adj.s - Adjective

Tags: punctuation

If I wanted to shorten the plural form of *adjective*, which would be the right way to do that?

1. Adj.-s
2. Adjs
3. Adj.s

Comment: The standard form is Adj, or Adjs for plural. For an adjective phrase use AdjP, or AdjPs for plural.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "standard",  it is the abbreviation that CEGL uses, and may be of use to researchers.  But it doesn't have much use in "standard" writing, unlike (say) cm for centimetre or UK for United Kingdom.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that.

There are some abbreviations that are common in dictionaries, and because learners use dictionaries a lot, they believe these abbreviations are common in English. Using "Adj" for "adjective" is one of these.

In any normal use of English, the word should be written out in full.

If you *are* writing a dictionary, you could use *Adjs*. But this is not standard.